# How to filter out cases with a certain score across several time points

Tags: r, dplyr

I have longitudinal data in long format where each case (id) has several rows of data for various time points (visit). Each case has a score at each visit, but not all cases have completed each visit.

I have two questions regarding how to filter out certain cases:

1. I want to select cases with a score equal to or above 6 across two or more visits. It does not matter which visits the score is equal to or above 6.
2. I want to select cases with a score below 6 across baseline to visit 4 (ie.not visit 5). Cases that do not have complete observations for baseline to visit 4 should be excluded.

I have tried several filtering steps using dplyr::filter and ifelse statements, but not succeeded thus far.

Does anyone have a good suggestion of how to accomplish this?

An example of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(01L, 01L, 01L, 01L, 01L, 01L, 
02L, 02L, 02L, 02L, 02L, 02L, 03L, 03L, 03L, 
03L, 03L, 03L, 06L, 06L, 07L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), visit = c("Baseline", "Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit3", "Visit4", "Visit5", 
"Baseline", "Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit3", "Visit4", "Visit5", "Baseline", "Visit1", "Visit2", 
"Visit3", "Visit4", "Visit5", "Baseline", "Visit1", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit4", "Visit5"
), score = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, 
26L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first condition, using `dplyr::filter()` with per-operation grouping using `.by`. (Note you'll have to update to dplyr >= v1.1.0 for this feature; otherwise you can `group_by(id)` before the `filter()`).

```
library(dplyr)

# select cases with a score equal to or above 6 across two or more visits
df %>%
  filter(sum(score >= 6) >= 2, .by = id)
```

```
   id    visit score
1   1 Baseline     2
2   1   Visit1     2
3   1   Visit2     6
4   1   Visit3     6
5   1   Visit4     8
6   1   Visit5    10
7   2 Baseline     6
8   2   Visit1     2
9   2   Visit2     6
10  2   Visit3     8
11  2   Visit4     8
12  2   Visit5     6
13 10 Baseline     9
14 10   Visit1     8
15 10   Visit2     8
16 10   Visit4     9
17 10   Visit5     9
```

The second condition would be:

```
df %>%
  filter(
    # select cases with a score below 6 across baseline to visit 4 (ie.not visit 5)
    all(score[visit != "Visit5"] < 6), 
    # Cases that do not have complte observations for baseline to visit 4 should be excluded
    length(visit[visit != "Visit5"]) == 5,
    .by = id
  )
```

```
  id    visit score
1  3 Baseline     2
2  3   Visit1     3
3  3   Visit2     4
4  3   Visit3     2
5  3   Visit4     1
6  3   Visit5     3
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(id = c(01L, 01L, 01L, 01L, 01L, 01L, 
                            02L, 02L, 02L, 02L, 02L, 02L, 03L, 03L, 03L, 
                            03L, 03L, 03L, 06L, 06L, 07L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), visit = c("Baseline", "Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit3", "Visit4", "Visit5", 
                                                                                              "Baseline", "Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit3", "Visit4", "Visit5", "Baseline", "Visit1", "Visit2", 
                                                                                              "Visit3", "Visit4", "Visit5", "Baseline", "Visit1", "Baseline", "Baseline", "Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit4", "Visit5"
                            ), score = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 
                                         3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                             26L), class = "data.frame")

# 1)
df |> 
  filter(visit != "Baseline") |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  summarise(n_score = sum(score >= 6)) |> 
  filter(n_score >= 2) |> 
  pull(id)
#> [1]  1  2 10

# 2)
df |> 
  filter(visit != "Visit5") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = visit, values_from = score) |> 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ .x < 6)) |> 
  pull(id)
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Solution to question 1 works as intended. However, when running the code for solution number 2 it does not select the case with id 3.

Comment: It does - you can see this from the output which was generated using the reprex package. Try running it again or updating your packages.